# WebView not run JS

Tags: xcode, uiwebview

I am trying to run this JS script on my WebView. This Script return's 2 script (1 Lib + 1 Image creator). When i run it on browser it runs perfect. But when i run it on mobile (WebView) i cant see anything.

```
NSString * script = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<body><body><script data-server=\"ADMAN|http://adman.gr/\">(function() {document.write('<sc'+'ript data-ws=\"1015\" data-h=\"sport-fm.adman.gr\" data-s=\"320x50\" data-iframe=\"false\" data-kw=\"\" data-p=\"\" src=\"http://static.adman.gr/adman.js\"></sc'+'ript>');}());</script></body></body>"];
 [_webview loadHTMLString:script baseURL:nil];
 [ _webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"function()" ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I met you issue before.

Here is my solution:

[image]

**put your script into a js file.** Then load the script,

```
static NSString *JSHandler;
JSHandler = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"script" withExtension:@"js"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:JSHandler];
```

Done!

Comment: @Cliff where did you load the script?

Comment: on viewDidload . The Script will be dynamic i will parse it from server with json. Its not a good solution to run internal js file.

Comment: @Cliff try put it into `- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` delegate

Comment: - (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    static NSString *JSHandler;
    JSHandler = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"index" withExtension:@"js"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [self.webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:JSHandler];
}   Sorry not Working.

Comment: alert('Test');  i add this in my function just for test